# Can I put square root on these matrices?

Tags: matrices

If $A$ and $B$ are nonnegative square matrices and $B^2$ =$P^T$$A^2$$P$ with $P$ a permutation matrix.
Can we deduce that  $B$ =$P^T$ $A$ $P$ ?

Comment: Nonnegative $=$ "all components are nonnegative"?

Comment: This amounts to asking if $P^{-1}=P^T$.  If yes then multiply $B$ by itself to obtain the desired result.

Comment: Yes all components are nonnegative